# Azure AD & Graph API Permission

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a variety of graph permissions assigned to different web apps in Azure. Is there any way in which I can map these graph permissions back to Azure AD roles and identify which role is the permission assigned to? I need this to implement access control based on the signed-in user

Comment: So basically you want to know if a user can do an action before doing the action, e.g. updating a group?

Comment: You should not do this and cannot do this.

For AAD Graph API permissions, they can be added into your app registration. So, the signed in user can delegated their directory permissions to your application. The back end logic is AAD will issue an access_token with AAD graph as the audience. It means that only AAD Graph API can validate the access_token with AAD Graph permissions.

Comment: If you just want to assign different roles with different permissions in Azure AD Graph API, please just kindly use Azure AD Directory Roles feature. Azure AD Graph API backend will validate the signed-in directory role actually.

Comment: juunas - yeah, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph permissions are granted for Azure AD app. Azure AD role is to manage Azure AD rather than API permission. There is no mapping between them.

What you are looking for is [appRole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

```
"appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Writer",
      "id": "d1c2ade8-98f8-45fd-aa4a-6d06b947c66f",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Writers Have the ability to create tasks.",
      "value": "{the custom role name}"
    }
  ]
```

A sample for your reference: [Authorization in a web app using Azure AD application roles & role claims](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/).

---

**Update**

You need to add the needed Graph permissions in Azure AD APP and then control the permissions in your code.

We assume you have [assigned a custom role in an Azure AD app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#declare-roles-for-an-application) and [added a user to this role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles).

When a user signs in, a token which includes the role claim will be returned.
You can judge the user's role in the code. If it matches a custom appRole, he is allowed to perform an operation, such as user-invite-all . If the user does not match any of the appRoles, he does not have permission to perform any operations.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Writer, Approver")]
public ActionResult TaskSubmit(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Writer"))
        //do something such as inviting others.
    {
```

Please dig deeper into the sample code I shared above.

**PS: Note that I have modified the value in "appRoles" in my previous answer.**

Comment: In the case of a delegated permission in Graph, the app runs on behalf of the signed-in user right? In that case, how does a permission in Graph gets mapped to AAD? For example, if I assign a user-invite-all delegated permission to the app which will be assumed by the user at run time, how do I know which AD role is that permission mapped to in AAD?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.